# How to use parenetheses in java code

Tags: java, netbeans

I am teaching myself Java and instead of the usual "hello World!" I thought it would be better to build a calculator app and learn Java whilst building it.

["JavaCalculator.png"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud8we.png)

My Question is: How can I program the "(" and ")" parenthesis keys so I can use them in my calculator app.

A typical number button (2) in my app is:

```
private void btnTwoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    if (bFinish == false) {
        String btnTwoText = txtDisplay.getText() + btnTwo.getText();
        dObtainer = Double.parseDouble(btnTwoText);
        txtDisplay.setText(btnTwoText);
    } else {
        txtDisplay.setText("");
        String btnTwoText = txtDisplay.getText() + btnTwo.getText();
        dObtainer = Double.parseDouble(btnTwoText);
        txtDisplay.setText(btnTwoText);
        bFinish = false;
    }
}
```

A typical operand button (-) in my app is:

```
private void btnMinusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String button_text = "-";
        getOperator(button_text);
}


private void getOperator(String btnText) {
        mathOperator = btnText.charAt(0);
        dTotal1 = dTotal1 + dObtainer;
        txtDisplay.setText("");
    }
```

And this is what happens when the "Equals" button is pressed.

```
private void btnEqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String sBuffer = "";

        switch (mathOperator) {
            case '+':
                dResult = dTotal1 + dObtainer;
                break;
            case '-':
                dResult = dTotal1 - dObtainer;
                break;
            case '/':
                dResult = dTotal1 / dObtainer;
                break;
            case '*':
                dResult = dTotal1 * dObtainer;
                break;
            case '^':
                dResult = Math.pow(dTotal1, dObtainer);
                break;
            case '(':
                sBuffer =  "(";
                //dResult = dObtainer;
                break;
        }

        mathOperator = '\0';
        dTotal1 = 0;
        dObtainer = 0;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
        if(!"(".equals(sBuffer))
                sBuffer = df.format(dResult);
        if(!")".equals(sBuffer))
                sBuffer = df.format(dResult);
        sBuffer = sBuffer.replace(".0", "");
        txtDisplay.setText(sBuffer);

        bFinish = true;
    }
```

Comment: Your code will never work correctly in its present form. Throw it all away and look up recursive descent expression parsing, or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Comment: Excuse me but it dose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner, I would suggest simply go with built-in [Javascript engine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/)

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String foo = "4+5+(8*4)"; //replace your expression here
System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
```

Another one you can use [MVEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVEL)

Comment: Thank you for your help, you have given me some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringBuilder` to create the expression (like `2+(1-5)`) and then use:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
...

ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String exp = sb.toString(); //sb is the string builder
int result = 0;
try {
    result = (int) engine.eval(exp);
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//from here you can use result in whatever way you want
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, you have give me some ideas.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this site and I am learning as I go. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction about answering questions.